# Фильтрация таблицы на jQuery

Tags: jquery, frontend

Здравствуйте,

Есть форма у которой в строке `.table-filters` находятся `<input/>`. Под фильтрами, в строках `.table-data` идут данные.

Как сделать простую фильтрацию по неполному совпадению введенного в `<input>` текста и данных таблицы? Если строка не удовлетворяет фильтрам, скрываем ее.

Мой вариант (естественно) не фильтрует данные.

```js
$('.table-filters input').on('input', function() {
  filterTable($(this).parents('table'));
});

function filterTable(table) {
  var filters = table.find('.table-filters td');
  var rows = table.find('.table-data');
  for (var rowKey in rows) {
    var currentRow = rows.eq(rowKey);
    var validRow = true;
    for (var columnKey in currentRow) {
      if (currentRow.children().eq(columnKey).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(
        filters.eq(columnKey).find('input').val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
        validRow = validRow && false;
      }
    }
    if (validRow === true) {
      currentRow.css('display', 'none');
    } else {
      currentRow.css('display', '');
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Товар</th>
    <th>Производство</th>
    <th>Цена</th>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table-filters'>
    <td>
      <input/>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input/>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table-data'>
    <td>Томаты</td>
    <td>Новосибирск</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table-data'>
    <td>Огурцы</td>
    <td>Кемерово</td>
    <td>65</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='table-data'>
    <td>Томаты</td>
    <td>Минусинск</td>
    <td>70</td>
  </tr>
  <tr class='cell'>
    <td>Картофель</td>
    <td>Красноярск</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.table-filters input').on('input', function () {
    filterTable($(this).parents('table'));
});

function filterTable($table) {
    var $filters = $table.find('.table-filters td');
    var $rows = $table.find('.table-data');
    $rows.each(function (rowIndex) {
        var valid = true;
        $(this).find('td').each(function (colIndex) {
            if ($filters.eq(colIndex).find('input').val()) {
                if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf(
                $filters.eq(colIndex).find('input').val().toLowerCase()) == -1) {
                    valid = valid && false;
                }
            }
        });
        if (valid === true) {
            $(this).css('display', '');
        } else {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
        }
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Товар</th>
        <th>Производство</th>
        <th>Цена</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class='table-filters'>
        <td>
            <input/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input/>
        </td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='table-data'>
        <td>Томаты</td>
        <td>Новосибирск</td>
        <td>80</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='table-data'>
        <td>Огурцы</td>
        <td>Кемерово</td>
        <td>65</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='table-data'>
        <td>Томаты</td>
        <td>Минусинск</td>
        <td>70</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='table-data'>
        <td>Картофель</td>
        <td>Красноярск</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```